# One-to-many relationship with composite primary key / foreign key

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities - Customer (Cust) and Order (Ord).  They are related as One-to-many - A Customer can have multiple Orders and an Order belongs to a single Customer.

The Customer entity has a composite primary key, which is also a foreign key in Order entity.

Here are the two entities PLUS the @IdClass:

```
package com.sample.test.domain.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Cust", schema = "test")
@IdClass(CustId.class)
public class CustEntity  implements Serializable {

  private Date deactivatedOn;
  private Integer id;
  private String name;

  public CustEntity() {
    }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "deactivatedOn", nullable = true)
  public Date getDeactivatedOn() {
  return deactivatedOn;
  }

  public void setDeactivatedOn(Date deactivatedOn){
  this.deactivatedOn = deactivatedOn;
  }

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  public Integer getId() {
  return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id){
  this.id = id;
  } 

  @Id
  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length =100)
  public String getName() {
  return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name){
  this.name = name;
  }

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cust", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) 
  public Set<OrdEntity> getOrdSet() { 
      return ordSet; 
  } 

  public void setOrdSet(Set<OrdEntity> ord) { 
      this.ordSet = ord; 
  } 

  private Set<OrdEntity> ordSet = new HashSet<OrdEntity>();

}




package com.sample.test.domain.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Date;
@Entity
@Table(name = "Ord", schema = "test")
public class OrdEntity  implements Serializable {

  private Date createdOn;
  private Date deactivatedOn;
  private Integer id;

  public OrdEntity() {
    }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "createdOn", nullable = false)
  public Date getCreatedOn() {
  return createdOn;
  }

  public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn){
  this.createdOn = createdOn;
  }


  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
  @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="custId", referencedColumnName="id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
          @JoinColumn(name="custName", referencedColumnName="name", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
  public CustEntity getCust() {
    return cust;
  }
  public void setCust(CustEntity cust) {
    this.cust = cust;
  }

  private CustEntity cust;
  @Basic
  @Column(name = "deactivatedOn", nullable = true)
  public Date getDeactivatedOn() {
  return deactivatedOn;
  }

  public void setDeactivatedOn(Date deactivatedOn){
  this.deactivatedOn = deactivatedOn;
  }

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  public Integer getId() {
  return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id){
  this.id = id;
  }

}



package com.sample.test.domain.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class CustId implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    public CustId() {

    }
    public CustId(Integer id,String name) {
        this.id =id;
        this.name =name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

When I try to get a list of Orders for a Customer, the generated hibernate query is throwing an exception.

Here is the query being generated:

```
select ordEntity
from com.sample.test.domain.model.OrdEntity ordEntity
where ordEntity.cust.id = ?1 and ordEntity.cust.name = ?2
```

## Exception

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: cust.id of: com.sample.test.domain.model.OrdEntity
```

Any idea why I am getting this exception?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't think you need to reference the `cust` since you don't have one. That is more typical with `@EmbeddedId`. Try `ordEntity.custId` and `ordEntity.custName`.

Comment: The query is generated by Hibernate; it's not something I wrote.  In any case, I tried to use ordEntity.custId and ordEntity.custName in the query, but it too failed with a similar exception:                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: custId of: com.sample.test.domain.model.OrdEntity [select ordEntity
from com.sample.test.domain.model.OrdEntity ordEntity
where ordEntity.custId = ?1 and ordEntity.custName = ?2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `@Embeddable` is a lot easier which I guess is why I always use that.

1) Can't use the `id` keyword.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CustId.class)
public class CustEntity implements Serializable {

    private Date deactivatedOn;
    private Integer val;
    private String name;

    public CustEntity() {
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "deactivatedOn", nullable = true)
    public Date getDeactivatedOn() {
        return deactivatedOn;
    }

    public void setDeactivatedOn(Date deactivatedOn) {
        this.deactivatedOn = deactivatedOn;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "val", nullable = false)
    public Integer getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(Integer val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cust", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<OrdEntity> getOrdSet() {
        return ordSet;
    }

    public void setOrdSet(Set<OrdEntity> ord) {
        this.ordSet = ord;
    }

    private Set<OrdEntity> ordSet = new HashSet<OrdEntity>();

}
```

and

```
public class CustId implements Serializable {

    private Integer val;
    private String name;
    public CustId() {

    }
    public CustId(Integer val,String name) {
        this.val = val;
        this.name =name;
    }

    public Integer getVal() {
        return val;
    }
    public void setVal(Integer val){
        this.val = val;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

2) Can't declare the forein key as `insertable = false, updatable = false`

```
@Entity
public class OrdEntity implements Serializable {

    private Date createdOn;
    private Date deactivatedOn;
    private Integer id;

    public OrdEntity() {
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "createdOn", nullable = false)
    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "custVal", referencedColumnName = "val"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "custName", referencedColumnName = "name") })
    public CustEntity getCust() {
        return cust;
    }

    public void setCust(CustEntity cust) {
        this.cust = cust;
    }

    private CustEntity cust;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "deactivatedOn", nullable = true)
    public Date getDeactivatedOn() {
        return deactivatedOn;
    }

    public void setDeactivatedOn(Date deactivatedOn) {
        this.deactivatedOn = deactivatedOn;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Then it seems to work just fine:

```
tx.begin();
CustEntity cust = new CustEntity();
cust.setVal(1);
cust.setName("name");
em.persist(cust);
OrdEntity ord = new OrdEntity();
ord.setId(1);
ord.setCust(cust);
ord.setCreatedOn(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
em.persist(ord);
tx.commit();
em.clear();

OrdEntity o = em.createQuery("select ord from OrdEntity ord where ord.cust.val = 1 and ord.cust.name = 'name'", OrdEntity.class).getSingleResult();
System.out.println(o);
```

which gives

```
create table CustEntity (name varchar(100) not null, val integer not null, deactivatedOn timestamp, primary key (name, val))
Hibernate: create table CustEntity (name varchar(100) not null, val integer not null, deactivatedOn timestamp, primary key (name, val))
create table OrdEntity (id integer not null, createdOn timestamp not null, deactivatedOn timestamp, custName varchar(100), custVal integer, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table OrdEntity (id integer not null, createdOn timestamp not null, deactivatedOn timestamp, custName varchar(100), custVal integer, primary key (id))
alter table OrdEntity add constraint FK1p8pydt8ubvr1ylolesmoxqig foreign key (custName, custVal) references CustEntity
Hibernate: alter table OrdEntity add constraint FK1p8pydt8ubvr1ylolesmoxqig foreign key (custName, custVal) references CustEntity
HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@34a97744'
Create
insert into CustEntity (deactivatedOn, name, val) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into CustEntity (deactivatedOn, name, val) values (?, ?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [name]
binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [1]
insert into OrdEntity (createdOn, custName, custVal, deactivatedOn, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into OrdEntity (createdOn, custName, custVal, deactivatedOn, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Thu Sep 05 18:05:24 MST 2019]
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [name]
binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [1]
binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [1]
HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
select ordentity0_.id as id1_1_, ordentity0_.createdOn as createdO2_1_, ordentity0_.custName as custName4_1_, ordentity0_.custVal as custVal5_1_, ordentity0_.deactivatedOn as deactiva3_1_ from OrdEntity ordentity0_ cross join CustEntity custentity1_ where ordentity0_.custName=custentity1_.name and ordentity0_.custVal=custentity1_.val and custentity1_.val=1 and custentity1_.name='name'
Hibernate: select ordentity0_.id as id1_1_, ordentity0_.createdOn as createdO2_1_, ordentity0_.custName as custName4_1_, ordentity0_.custVal as custVal5_1_, ordentity0_.deactivatedOn as deactiva3_1_ from OrdEntity ordentity0_ cross join CustEntity custentity1_ where ordentity0_.custName=custentity1_.name and ordentity0_.custVal=custentity1_.val and custentity1_.val=1 and custentity1_.name='name'
extracted value ([id1_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [1]
extracted value ([createdO2_1_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2019-09-05 18:05:24.066]
extracted value ([custName4_1_] : [VARCHAR]) - [name]
extracted value ([custVal5_1_] : [INTEGER]) - [1]
extracted value ([deactiva3_1_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [null]
model.OrdEntity@1e886a5b
HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:h2:mem:test]
```

3) Using `@EmbeddedId` probably won't give you a `cross join` in your query.

Comment: Thank you for your response - the solution you provided works, but I am still perplexed as to why...You said "1) Can't use the id keyword."  Is it that we cannot use the variable name "id" for one of the keys in a composite primary key?  Is this a JPA specification?

Comment: Don't know about JPA but it seems to confuse Hibernate. Beyond that I didn't look.